# Autodesk a360 viewer does not show walkthrough tool

Tags: viewer, autodesk, forge, walkthrough

When using Autodesk a360 viewer from a public link or from a360 account, there is no walkthrough tool even though the model is 3D.  Is walkthrough tool only available using an embedded viewer?

Here is the public link:

https://myhub.autodesk360.com/ue28dee88/g/shares/SHabee1QT1a327cf2b7a6bf27cab740075fe?viewState=NoIgbgDAdAjCA0IDeAdEAXAngBwKZoC40ARXAZwEsBzAOzXjQEMyzd1C0IYBjAI14DsAEwAsAWgG8ArIzEiRQgWICcuAdzEAzZcs0AmEYMZCAbELQBfEAF0gA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u try adding the walkthrough extension ? its in the SDK provided ...